# Make web project writable by apache and other user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, apache-httpd

I am running **ubuntu 12.04 LTS** . To be able to view my web project in the browser I did the following:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/project
```

Now I wanted to open the project in netbeans but it has not the permissions to read or write. So I created another group called netbeans and added the current user and www-data user to that group.

```
chgrp -R netbeans /var/www/project
```

but netbeans still cannot write or even read. And it seams that apache only can read the project folder when its owner is www-data.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I think you also have to update `/etc/apache2/envvars` but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, assuming you want to allow the users `www-data` and `netbeans` to access `/var/www/project` by adding both of them to the group `netbeans`:

```
# you might have done this already, but no harm will be done by
# executing these commands again:
groupadd netbeans
adduser www-data netbeans
adduser netbeans

# set the user 'www-data' and the group 'netbeans' as the owners
chown www-data:netbeans -R /var/www/project
# allow group members to read and write files
chmod g+rw -R /var/www/project
```

Answer (score 0):

What user does netbeans run as? Most likely not `www-data` (as that is Apache, I think), but if you can find out you can add the user of netbeans to the group named `www-data` and that should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you are logged as `abc` and launched `netbean`, then `abc` user should have the permission for read and write. This you can set as

```
chmod -R 775 /var/www/project
```

and

```
chown -R www-data:abc /var/www/project
```

Comment: Marking every file in `/var/www/project` as executable is really bad style, to say the least...